# Pydev interactive console - output does not appear when using "if"

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

If I type

```
if 1: print("yes")
```

in an interactive console in Pydev, there is no output. This happens whether I choose "Console for currently active editor" or "Python console". Why is this, and how can I fix it?

If I type the same line in IDLE, or in Python within the Windows Command Prompt, I get the output `yes` as expected (after pressing Enter twice). If I type just `print("yes")` in the interactive console in Pydev, I also get the output `yes` as expected.

I am using Python 3.6, Eclipse 4.4.1, Pydev 3.8.0.201409251235, and Windows 10.

Comment: Works as expected in Python 3.5, Eclipse 4.6.3, Pydev 6.2.0.201711281614, Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to Eclipse 4.7.1a and Pydev 6.2.0.201711281614, and now the interactive console works as expected.

I would still be interested in knowing why the earlier versions had this problem.